# Android ListView with Custom Adapter, slow loading

Tags: android, listview

I have a Custom Adapter for the ListView. The Layout has three images, some text. When loading the Listview, it takes a while, because of the images. Its something like Posts.

Same app in iOS is loading very fast, I think that UITableView works different than Listview.

Is there a way, in place to load all posts, only load for example 3 posts and when the user scrolls the Listview down, load the next 3, scroll down, load the next 3 and so on. This could give a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, android listview work that way. Let's say there are 5 views that user can reach at the moment. ListView creates 9 views and when user scrolls it loads the bottom ones. You can think it this way. 
 Your main problem is how are you loading your images and create the custom view.
 There is a common pattern for custom adapters which handles the fast recycling views(ViewHolder pattern). You should checkout the link for ViewHolder pattern. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: For the images I am using Glide. Anyhow, let's say I have around 100 posts and loading all of them in the Custom Adapter. When the loading is done, I use the adapter in ListView. I think that is the problem.

I think that only loading for example 5 posts and than use only them in the Listview.

When the user scrolls to the end of the 5 posts, load in the same Custom Adapter 5 more posts. I don't know if this will automatically update the ListView, having now 10 posts.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html checkout this link as well.

Answer (score 0):

It probably loads slow because the images should be resized every time, if you could save thumbnails it would go much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Recycler View instead? As long as I know using the Recycler View is the best practice nowadays. You can find a very good tutorial here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html

You use the Recycler View almost the same way you do with List View: adapter, viewHolder, etc. It's good to mention though that you need to pay special attention to the use of the LayoutManager since the Recycler View it itself doesn't "know how to draw" the stuff on the screen.